# Twython 401 on stream, but REST works fine

Tags: rest, twitter, http-status-code-401, twython

**NO KIDDING. My code was working yesterday**

So I'm writing a script to get streaming data using twython. But today it's giving me 401 errors. Even with the [example code](https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/streaming_api.html)

I tried new keys, and a new app, but it still gives me 401.

However, normal REST api interface in Twython (see next code block) works just fine.

```
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
print twitter.get_home_timeline()
```

Some Googlefu led me to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438943/twython-oauth1-issues-401-error-using-example-code) which suggested using `ntpd -q`, but this doesn't solve my issue!

Comment: FWIW, I have the same problem.  Strangely, connecting to the streaming API works from my dev box (no 401) but doesn't work from my production server.  I have no idea why.  Clocks on both servers are in the same time.  If I had to guess, I'd guess that the clock on one of Twitter's servers has drifted, and my dev and production boxes are connecting to different IPs.

Comment: @VilleLaurikari For me, it works on heroku, but not on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

This affects only some of the servers behind `stream.twitter.com`.  Perhaps their clocks are off.

Some kind of geo-aware load balancing appears to be used and can the domain name resolves to a number of different IP addresses, depending on where you are doing the resolving.

Connecting to `199.59.148.229` or `199.59.148.138` gives the 401 error for me (these I get resolving from AWS Oregon), but `199.16.156.20` works (this I get resolving from my home network).

Therefore, my temporary workaround for this was to add this to `/etc/hosts`:

```
199.16.156.20 stream.twitter.com
```

I expect the original problem to go away in a few hours, but this works for me, for now.